# Symfony HTTPKernel Component raise a fatal error because of Config Component

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, config, symfony-kernel

I've got a fatal error when I try to simply use the HttpKernel Component.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator' not found in /.../vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Config/FileLocator.php on line 23
```

All packages has been install via composer 1.8.x
The setup is minimalist

PHP 5.6

```
symfony/dependency-injection          v3.4.27             Symfony DependencyInjection Component
symfony/event-dispatcher              v3.4.27             Symfony EventDispatcher Component
symfony/http-foundation               v3.4.27             Symfony HttpFoundation Component
symfony/http-kernel                   v3.4.27             Symfony HttpKernel Component
symfony/process                       v3.4.27             Symfony Process Component
symfony/yaml                          v3.4.27             Symfony Yaml Component
```

I do not want to install all symfony/symfony package.

The facts is that symfony/config is a "require-dev" dependency and seems not to be installed.
What I usually understand is that require-dev installation is normally install when you just run `composer install|update`. 
Apparently not...

Follow the code below

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel as SymfonyKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Config\FileLocator;

class MyKernel extends SymfonyKernel {

  public function boot() {
    // ...
    $this->iamOnError();
    // ...
  }

  public function iamOnError() {
    // @see SymfonyKernel::getContainerLoader
    $locator = new FileLocator($this);
  }

}
```

```php
use App\MyKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new MyKernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

My solution is to add "symfony/config" in the root composer.json... This is a kind weird...

So my question is why I've got this error (I know that symfony/config is not installed), or why symfony/config is not a "require" in composer.json for symfony/http-kernel component.

Comment: So does "composer require symfony/config --dev" fix the problem?  Can't really say why it was not installed automatically.  Unless maybe you installed the packaged using a production filter.

Comment: Yep, but:
"You are using the deprecated option "dev". Dev packages are installed by default now."

So it does not work too...

Comment: I don't have a 5.6 machine handy but was able to install kernel 4.2 under 7.3.  The config was not loaded by default which was a bit surprising but a composer require --dev symfony/config brought it right in as expected.  Maybe you need to specify the config version?  Just a guess.  Maybe try a fresh project and just require the kernel followed by config.

Comment: use symfony/config in the require part of composer.json will do the job but I wanted to know if I was misunderstanding something.
Thank you for your help by the way ;)

Comment: Turns out that the config component is optional for http-kernel.  I got: "symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/console" along with various other suggestions which makes sense.  You can certainly use the kernel without the config stuff.  So you only load it if you need it.